# Can I start a junit test from an intellij plugin

Tags: junit, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have a database that stores my test results.  I'm interested in writing a plugin for intellij13 that will let me rerun the test failures from the database using the JUnit run configuration.  I can't find any documentation on this.

I'd like to see an example for some method like:

`public void runTest(String testClass, String testName) {...}`

Comment: [How do I run JUnit tests from inside my java application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543912/how-do-i-run-junit-tests-from-inside-my-java-application)

Comment: @kukido My question isn't about running JUnit tests programmatically in general. I'd like to take advantage of the run action intellij already provides.

Comment: I apologize, bad question comprehension. Last time I looked into available option in 12.x, and there were no public classes available to create JUnit run configuration. I did not check 13.x, maybe it became more open. I suggest to get source code for Community Edition and look for JUnit run configuration. Please update the question if you find something interesting.

Comment: Added answer with the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked into IntelliJ 13.x and I was able to create JUnit runtime configuration. You need to do the following.

In your `META-INF/plugin.xml` add dependency on JUnit plugin, otherwise necessary JUnit plugin classes will not be available in your plugin class loader.

```
<depends optional="false">JUnit</depends>
```

Here's the sample code to create JUnit runtime configuration. Although it works, it is just a stub, you will have to populate all attributes.

```
import com.intellij.execution.RunManager;
import com.intellij.execution.impl.RunManagerImpl;
import com.intellij.execution.impl.RunnerAndConfigurationSettingsImpl;
import com.intellij.execution.junit.JUnitConfigurationType;
import com.intellij.openapi.project.Project;
...
RunManagerImpl runManager = (RunManagerImpl) RunManager.getInstance(project);
JUnitConfigurationType type = JUnitConfigurationType.getInstance();
RunnerAndConfigurationSettingsImpl runnerAndConfigurationSettings = (RunnerAndConfigurationSettingsImpl)runManager.createRunConfiguration("junit test run", type.getConfigurationFactories()[0]);
runManager.addConfiguration(runnerAndConfigurationSettings, false);
```

And here we go, JUnit run configuration.

[image]

Comment: Actually I see no `com.intellij.execution.junit.JUnitConfigurationType` class. Can you please update your answer? I need to run a **test class (a class which has @Test annotation)**  using its `Virtual File` (or `PsiFile`) as input from my IntelliJ Plugin.