# How can I use WebDriverWait for various methods in Selenium JUnit?

Tags: java, selenium, junit4

I have various methods in my code in which I need to use [WebDriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html). Usually we declare it in the main method like:

```
WebDriverWait mywait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 25)
```

While using JUnit in Selenium, there isn't any main method. How can I use WebDriverWait for webelements in various methods in my code?

Answer (score 0):

#### Way you can call your JUnit function from main

Here is some help on how to: *[How do I run JUnit tests from inside my Java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543912/how-do-i-run-junit-tests-from-inside-my-java-application)*

#### Or you can simply add Thread.sleep(millisecond)

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(100);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It must work in Java ([Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29)).

But you can also use (I think it is better for testing):

```
FluentWait fluentWait = new FluentWait<>(webDriver) {
  .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .pollingEvery(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
}

WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
   .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));
```

Source: *[How can make it wait until an element is present in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903231/how-to-wait-until-an-element-is-present-in-selenium/20903328#20903328)*