# Invoke JUnit from main application, injecting custom @Test

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, manual-testing

How can I invoke JUnit core to start a test run, and inject a custom `@Test` method?

I know that [by using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2562575/1790644)

```
JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
Result result = junit.run();
```

I can start a JUnit test run and get the final result, and I know that by adding a [RunListener](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html) I can get a method call on each phase of execution - Is there any way to break this down further into the individual `Before` / `Test` / `After` calls?

In addition, is there a way that I would be able to substitute a method to be run instead of the given `@Test` method definition?

The context of the question is that there is an automation test base that has large overlap with a manual test base - whose testing can share the same `@Before`, and `@After` events, and only the `@Test` methods would be substituted; this would greatly ease the load on the manual testers.

I would like to be as non-intrusive to the existing test base as possible.

Short of re-rolling my own JUnit framework, would there be a way to, even using reflection, substitute each test method?