# Is it possible to start a test run of a JUnit 5 test class from within Java?

Tags: java, junit5

I found instructions on how to start a JUnit 4 test case from within Java, but have been unable to put together constructs that will fire up tests on a JUnit 5 test case.

The JUnit 4 solution I tried was this: [How do I run JUnit tests from inside my java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543912/how-do-i-run-junit-tests-from-inside-my-java-application)

I've been trying to get the ConsoleLauncher in JUnit5 to work, but it is throwing exceptions. That was documented here: http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher

I'd like to automate starting tests to match running a program to simplify the instructions I'm providing when I provide unit tests to students.

Thanks!

Comment: did u try that line: `import org.junit.Test;`?  ,also i think Every test method in JUnit must be annotated with the @Test , **example :** `import org.junit.Test;
public class VintageTest {
    @Test
   public static void main(String args[]) {
  org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main("junitfaq.SimpleTest");
}

@Test
    void test() {
        assertEquals("key", pair.getKey());
        assertEquals("val", pair.getValue());
    }
}` .

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try as well as looking into Maven or Gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to simplify a task for students, I think it would be good to use a build tool like Maven or Gradle. This makes it simple to run tests, build their code, etc. JUnit5 tests can be run by using plugins - http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build.

Comment: Agreed.  The students need to have some exposure to build tools.  And by the sounds of it, so does the OP.