# How to make acces to src.test package from main class in Java or how to run test class from main class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I try to launch `selenium` test from main class and try to follow the example from next question: [How do I run JUnit tests from inside my java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543912/how-do-i-run-junit-tests-from-inside-my-java-application) :

```
JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
Result result = junit.run(testClasses);
```

But I cannot use this resolve because I have not access to my test class from main class:

[image]

---

**Queation:** How to correctly run test class from main class?

---

**PS**

I need to run test class from main class since is necessary build executable `jar` file and launched the `selenium` test from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

classes in `test` folders are not included in application after build, so if you want to run `PageTest` from your main classes, make sure your `PageTest` class is not in `test` folder.

Comment: Do I just need to move `PageTest` from the` / test` folder to any project folder?

Comment: yes . moving from `test` folder to another, your `PageTest` class become usual class, and you can use it everywhere.